# Select rows where Col1 "isnull" & Col2 "notnull"

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to select rows where value in col1 is null and value in col2 is not null
DF

```
col1  col2
423   NaN
NaN   291
391   102
```

Desired output

```
col1 col2
NaN  291
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas loc`:

```
df.loc[(df['col1'].isna()) & (~df['col2'].isna())]
```